# How to merge left join with two separate column names and get only column from left table

Tags: pandas

Two data frames df1 and df2

Need to join user_id of df1 with id of df2

```
df1.merge(df2, how=left, left_on='user_id', right_on='id')
```

The above will be having columns from both table.

Q1: But how to print only the left table

Q2: how to print only `user_id` the from left table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `isin`

```
df1[df1.user_id.isin(df2.id)]
```

And

```
df1.loc[df1.user_id.isin(df2.id),'user_id']
```